# Logs may or may not be displayed in Apps Script dashboard

Tags: google-apps-script, logging

I use console.log to display my logs.
But Logs may or may not be displayed in Apps Script dashboard.

The following message is written where the log is displayed.
「There may be a delay in logging recent executions.」

Is there any way to reliably get the logs without using Google Cloud Platform Project?

Comment: For example, how about storing the log on Google Spreadsheet? And/or, for example, if your script is run on Google Spreadsheet, how about showing the log on a dialog on Spreadsheet? I thought that in this case, there are several directions. But, if those were not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

You need `Logger.log()` to display logs, and you will watch it in "Execution"

[image: Execution Menu]

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging

But, if you deployed as Web App, and this is client-side JS running, you can use `console.log()` and watch it in browser console

Comment: From the reference "You can use either the Logger or console logging services in the built-in execution log."

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I am currently working on a connector for the data portal.
The log is output when the report is displayed, so it cannot be run manually.
Logs are not almost always displayed, but sometimes they are.